# Eliminar cookies del navegar por methodo C#

Tags: c#

Buenas Tardes Comunidad,

Quiero saber si ahí alguna forma de al momento de dar click en un botón este pueda eliminarme los cookies que tiene el navegador.

Esta gestión seria por c#

Comment: ¿Serían las cookies de todas las páginas visitadas? ¿Serían las cookies de tu aplicación? Agregando más detalles a tu pregunta sería más clara de lo que deseas realizar, también cosas que has investigado y posibles soluciones que hayas tomado en cuenta. Todo esto para saber exactamente lo que requieres y poder darte una solución más ideal.

Comment: Este botón solo haría esta acción?

Comment: que tipo de aplicacion estas creando? es web o desktop, lo pregunto porque es el browser quien tiene acceso a las cookies y esto dependera de del browser

Comment: Gracias por sus aportes, respondiendo a @Flxtr si serian los cookies del navegador en el cual me encuentro.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini es web la aplicacion

Comment: pero si es web entonces es correcto lo comentado por @amoo, si quieres eliminar una cookie debes expirar el tiempo, para que cuando llegue ese dato al browser la quite. La siguiene parte que comenta de eliminar el archivo no aplicaria

Answer (score 2):

Depende del navegador, ya que todos no guardan las cookies en un mismo archivo.
En el caso de Google Chrome que guarda las cookies en:

> C:\Users(User)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Cookies

El codigo en C# seria,

```
System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Users\(User)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
Data\Cookies");
```

En el caso de los demas navegadores tendras que buscar en su documentacion donde se encuentra el archivo donde guardan sus cookies y borrarlas.

Answer (score -1):

Quieres eliminar las de tu web o todas las del navegador? 
Podrias intentar esto...

```
string[] cookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
    foreach (string cookie in cookies)
    {
        BulletedList1.Items.Add("Deleting " + cookie);
        Response.Cookies[cookie].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    }
```

o si requieres eliminar todas las del navegador, puedes eliminar directo el archivo en el que se guardan con System.IO.File.Delete("Ruta del archivo");